# How to access shared locations between two Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2003

I have two Amazon EC2 Instances running Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.0. Both the instances are created in the same region and have the same Security Group. I enables icmp for all ports and connection methods, and am able to successfully ping between both my instances. However, when I try to access the shared locations of one EC2 instance feom another, using:

```
\\<elastic-ip>
```

or

```
\\<internal-private-ip>
```

I am unable to see the shared locations, and get an error saying:

```
No Network Provider accepted the given network path
```

I am able to trace from both EC2 instances using the tracert command.

Please let me know of a way to accessed shared locations between two EC2 instances.

Thanks

P.S.: I know that this can alternatively be achieved using S3, but do not wish to use it for different reasons.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault, I think

Comment: I agree with @bdonlan, this should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own query, and here it is:

**Theory:**

This can be found at [this Microsoft knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298804) which deals with the ways to enable Microsoft file sharing SMB. The below matter is of relevance:

> The following ports are associated
>   with file sharing and server message
>   block (SMB) communications:
>
> - Microsoft file sharing SMB: User Datagram Protocol (UDP) ports from 135
>     through 139 and Transmission Control
>     Protocol (TCP) ports from 135 through
>     139.
> - Direct-hosted SMB traffic without a network basic input/output system
>     (NetBIOS): port 445 (TCP and UPD).

**How to do it:**

1. Enable the above ports in the security group associated with your EC2 Instance. Once you have done this, your Security Group Permissions should look something like the image below:
   [image: EC2 Security Group Permissions]
2. Enable the ports in the windows firewalls of both the instances. A detailed method to do so can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308127). Skip step 7 for Windows Server.

This solves the issue, however, a restart of the instances might be needed.

Comment: Verified.  Need to enable "Windows File Sharing" in firewall config if you use Windows firewall.  Also, for this to work, you need to explicitly share a folder to the other machine.